# state in useEffect second arguement Infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks, fetch-api, mern

i have this small piece of code where i think i guess I'm doing it wrong

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  fetch('/getOrders',{
      headers:{
       "Content-Type":"application/json",
       "Authorization": "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("jwt")

      }
  }).then(res=>res.json())
  .then(orderList=>{
      setOrders(orderList)
      //console.log("myAdmin",orderList)

    
  }).catch(err=>{
      console.log("Error in Catch",err)
  })
  }, [orders])
```

Here the data is updated overtime by itself and i want my state updated every time the fetch data is different to the existing state , but regardless if the data is different or not, the state keep updating making the component re-render infinitely. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I don't see how `orders` is a dependency, but basically anytime an effect unconditionally updates a value that is in its dependency array it will cause render looping. So basically you want to, on every render, fetch the data, and only if it is different, update local state?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, That's pretty much what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

Anytime an effect unconditionally updates a value that is in its dependency array it will cause render looping.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch('/getOrders', { ... })
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(orderList=>{
      setOrders(orderList); // <-- updates state, triggers rerender
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      ...
    });
}, [orders]); // <-- updated state triggers effect callback
```

## Possible Solution

It appears you are wanting to fetch every time the component renders and upon successful response (200 OK) check if the `orders` array is *actually* different. If it is then update state, otherwise ignore the update.

1. Remove the dependency array so the `useEffect` hook callback is called each time the component renders.
2. Check if the `fetch` request response is `ok` before accessing the response JSON data.
3. Check the `order` response data against state. If the arrays are different lengths, update state, otherwise you will need to check element by element to determine if the array is different or not. *

Updated effect hook

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/getOrders", {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("jwt")
    }
  })
    .then((res) => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("Fetch is not OK");
      }
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((orderList) => {
      if (orders.length !== orderList.length) {
        setOrders(orderList);
      } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
          // *** Your actual equality condition may be different, i.e. if they are objects ***
          if (orders[i] !== orderList[i]) {
            setOrders(orderList);
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("Error in Catch", err);
    });
});
```

* This is an `O(n)` check *every time* so an optimization that can be made may be to also return and store an "update" hash. If the hash is the same as the previous request, skip state update. This could be something as simple as generating a new GUID for the update in backend and returning it with data.

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly `[orders]` in your code means: call what inside useEffect each time orders change, and each time useEffect is called , it update again the orders ... and you get your infinite loop

```
  useEffect(() => {
     
  }, [orders])
```

you should change `[orders]` into  `[]`.

`res=>res.json()` will create a new refrance to your object, and changing your referance to your object means it changed, for example `[1,2,3]` if you pass again `[1,2,3]` it will not be the same objct even thow it looks the same. `v=[1,2,3]`, you pass v, and then `v[0]=-1`, passe v again it will be considred the same since it has the same referance.

Best way to fix this is to compare them manualy depending on your case, and when they aren't the same, you use somthing like `[...orders]` which will create new refrence and it will invoke useEffect again.

Comment: but where wont comparing the data within use Effect, still cause infinite looping? assuming i put orders within the 2nd arguement?

Comment: no, you can't , use effect isn't the thing, worst case use timer or something to chech each 1 minutes

Comment: Yeh, that helps at least instead of the infinite looping

Answer (score 0):

try to set state with prevState argument, so you will not have to include any dependency.

```
setOrders((prevState) => ({
   ...prevState, orderList
}))
```